# Jquery Smooth Scrolling anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a problem, so basically, I tried to add a smooth scrolling with jquery, I want to have a smooth scrolling everytime I click in my navbar anchor link, I tried to do it by myself but it's not working, any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

```
// Smooth Scroll to div
$(".ser").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate(
    {
      scrollTop: $("#services").offset().top
    },
    1000
  );
});
```

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="brand">
      <h2>Kataki</h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="links">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="active">
          Home
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="ser" href="#">
          About
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Testimonials</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="services" class="services">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Our Services</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried it in a pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKMNjy?editors=1111 and it works. I had to add some height to the elements to make it scroll though. Could that have been the issue for you, there might not have been anything to scroll?

Comment: your code should work fine. what is your problem? Check if there was error in browser's developer tool

Comment: Here's what the console says 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).animate is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (main.js:34)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)

Comment: I just solved it the problem so basically It's because of the jQuery version you use. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js

slim version of jQuery does not contain all the original jQuery functions.

You should use a full version. 
Thanks everyone for helping, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the slim build of jQuery, which doesn't include most of the library. Instead, you should be using the full version and just need to put your script in document ready event :

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script>
    // Smooth Scroll to div
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ser").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate(
    {
  scrollTop: $("#services").offset().top
},1000
);
 });
  });
   </script>
```

I tried this [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FT2KJVQ7HW9V) and it worked fine. if this doesn't solve your issue then you probably have another java script error in your code.
I hope it helps.

Comment: i tried your code and everything was fine , maybe you have another java script error in console.

Comment: Actually i just solved it, i just needed to download the full version jquery, thanks for helping mohammad!